# How to get the makespan time() value in a output element?

Tags: anylogic

I have this code On destroy of my Main:

```
// Stop the simulation when all the jobs are done

if (jobs.size() == 0) {
    makespan = time();
    getEngine().finish(); // Pausiere die Simulation
    getEngine().getState();
}
```

Ive got 2 maybe simple Questions:

1. I use the code getEngine().finish(); but my Simulation don't stop, the time still run. What is
   wrong ???
2. i have this output element, but i don't get the time, even if i stop the Model myself, because the code above don't seems to work:

[image]

And a text element to get the time in another spot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model does not finish because you call it in the "on destroy" of Main, which is only called when a model finishes. (It's like wondering why your lights do not turn off but you never toggle the light switch)

You need to call the `.finish()` elsewhere from within the model.

PS: Always only ask 1 question on SOF, keeps things simple, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, i called the ".finish" and the "time()" in the "enter" of my sink Block. Now both works.

Comment: if you find a reply useful, pls upvote it and mark it as answered, helps future users with similar problems, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote